# Sorting a linked list in parallel using Insertion Sort

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, ipc, shared-memory

I have an assignment where I must write a C program that sorts a linked list of earthquakes according to magnitude in multiple processes. For this first part of the assignment our teacher will only allow us to use multiple processes instead of threads.

So far I'm able to sort a the list of earthquakes in one process, but I am not sure how I would split the linked list and sort each piece in different processes. I have been looking into using shared memory but I am unsure how I can properly use it.

Is there a better way to solve this problem? If not, how can I use shared memory to sort the list of earthquakes using insertion sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue with a linked list in shared memory is getting all processes to have the same virtual address for the shared memory:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366763(v=vs.85).aspx

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html

http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap

I don't know if you're using Linux or Windows.

If the base address for the shared memory isn't the same, then as noted in the msdn article, pointers are usually replaced with offsets from the base address. I'm not sure if a linked list using a next "offset" versus a next "pointer" is what is intended for this assignment.

Also, the assignment mentions using insertion sort, so is insertion sort or a variation of insertion sort to be used to merge the sorted lists created by the processes, or are you allowed to use a merge list function to merge the lists?

Comment: The assignment is only meant to run on Unix based systems and we are allowed to use a merge list function to merge the lists.

Comment: Nodes are supposed to be sent to the other processes.

Comment: @mwharrisjr - so how are the nodes supposed to be sent between processes, something like pipes or something else?

Comment: My teacher said we could use pipes, files, shared memory, or message queues.

Comment: @mwharrisjr - some sort of synchronization will be needed, so a message queue could work, with each process having a queue for receiving nodes from the main process, and separate queue from each process when sending the sorted nodes back to the main process. The next pointer in a node could be used as a flag, non-null means more nodes will be send, and null could be used for a dummy node to mean that the previous node was the last node and for a process to change to it's next state (like from sorting to returning nodes). This won't be efficient, but I don't think efficiency is the goal here.

Answer (score 2):

How about using merge sort and multithreading?
Every division of array creates a new thread and at the end, sync thread output. So, for depth n, there will be <(2^n+1) threads.
Hence, you are sorting the linked list parallely and also no case of resource mishandling is there.

Sorry, not enough repo to write it in comment.

Comment: I failed to mention this, but for the first part of the assignment we have to use multiple processes and then for the next part we are to use multiple threads to sort, timing both methods and comparing the time used to sort the list.

Comment: The assignment is to use insertion sort.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the quicksort is simpler for parallelizing than the mergesort. The reason is that you have to do only a sequential pass for partitioning (with the mergesort you will require two, partitioning and merge). Once partitioned the array (or list), the sequence is divided in two independents parts; they will never require an additional processing, because the pivot is already at its definitive place.

However, the quicksort could degrade en O(n^2) if the pivot is wrongly chosen. Take care about that

Respect to the number of threads, I would recommend a fixed number not greater than the number of cores. And here again the quicksort is easier. For example, if you have 4 threads, then you use a first thread for doing the first partition. Then, you use two threads for doing 4 partitions. With these 4 partitions, you assign each partition to each thread. When the 4 threads joins the calling thread, then the array will be sorted.